# JQuery/CSS animation brekas after a while

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-transitions

i have build a realy simple animation with jQuery and CSS. I just transform the objects with jquery, the transition it self is a css transition. It works like expected but if i switch the browser tab and come back to the site later again, the animation is doing crazy things. boxes flying fast from right to left, but the animation should be from left to right.

this is how the animation works:

```
 $('#importance-healthy-text').css({ 'transform': 'translateX(1000px)', 'opacity': '0' });
        $('#importance-healthy-text').one('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd',
            function (e) {
                $('#importance-healthy-text').addClass('hidden');
                $('#importance-healthy-text').css({ 'transform': 'translateX(-1000px)', 'opacity': '0' });
                $(this).off(e);
                $('#importance-nachhaltig-text').removeClass('hidden');
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#importance-nachhaltig-text').css({ 'transform': 'translateX(0px)', 'opacity': '1' });
                }, 20);
            });
```

look at this plunker for the full code:

https://plnkr.co/edit/oHrvz1xwhxJ25XOOidpQ?p=preview

It would be very cool if anybody has an idea how i can solve this!

Comment: why don't you do full JS animation? I guess either the CSS or the JS animation pauses on tab switch and then, when you get back, they are desynced

Comment: This is a good point. It was just an idea to use css and JQuery and it was easy to do

Comment: thank you, i have changed the animation and just use jquery now. Now it works.

Comment: I will add an answer with it so you can set it as accepted if my suggestion helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from either the CSS or the JS animation being paused when switching tabs. When you get back to the tab with your animation, the animation frames are desynced so you get that result.

Using animation only with JS would help in your case.